# How can I detect change in account in Metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask, accounts

When a user changes to a different account in metamask, is there a way to detect it asynchronously in code?

I currently use

```
this.web3.eth.getAccounts((err, accs) => {   
  this.account = accs[0];
});
```

but when the account is changed, it still picks up the previous one. 
Refreshing the page is not a way to go. Did anyone face this and has a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, the method most people used is polling for changes using setIntervals. The only other option is checking if accounts match before each call.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As suggested by [Metamask FAQs](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#ear-listening-for-selected-account-changes) this might be an option:

```js
var account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
var accountInterval = setInterval(function() {
  if (web3.eth.accounts[0] !== account) {
    account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
    updateInterface();
  }
}, 100);
```

## edit

In the newer version metamask exposes an event that could be used to detect whether there's an account change as per [new doc](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#accountschanged):

```js
window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
  // Time to reload your interface with accounts[0]!
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment, checking in a loop is the only supported method.

Comment: Be careful though, I had a problem where I was always matching the if condition because the account I get was always lowercase.

Comment: I use and suggest to use onFocus event to handle this issue.

Comment: Is there a similar solution for the TronLink extension (tronWeb)?

Answer (score 34):

From the [MetaMask docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#using-the-provider):

```
window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
  // Time to reload your interface with accounts[0]!
})

window.ethereum.on('networkChanged', function (networkId) {
  // Time to reload your interface with the new networkId
})
```

As [@Sr.PEDRO](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/44236/sr-pedro) has noted, `ethereum.publicConfigStore` will not work in the future. In fact, it will be removed entirely. See [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/8077#issuecomment-663737672) for details.

You can also prevent MetaMask from automatically reloading web page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Prevent reload"
}
```

This only applies if you use the `window.web3` object injected by MetaMask, which is also [scheduled to be removed](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/8077).

Comment: Is there a similar solution for the TronLink extension (tronWeb)?

Comment: The docs url has changed, go to  https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#table-of-contents

Comment: How to change the connected account, I used this code but the event if not fired when I switch account in metamask plugin.

Answer (score 23):

Using web3 version 1.0.0, the metamask provider exposes an 'update' event you can listen to on it's publicConfigStore.

```
web3.currentProvider.publicConfigStore.on('update', callback);
```

Your callback will be passed an object with 'selectedAddress' and 'networkVersion' whenever those attributes change.

Comment: Hi Brian, where can I find documentation about the update event? Have searched the web3 1.0 docs. Thanks.

Comment: On the new metamask version  the name has changed, now you have to use `web3.currentProvider._publicConfigStore.on('update', callback);` 
But this is probably not going to be supported by metamask in the future so i would recomend using window.ethereum events https://medium.com/metamask/breaking-changes-to-the-metamask-inpage-provider-b4dde069dd0a

Answer (score 5):

You could put in useEffect a listenEvent like below:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function listenMMAccount() {
      window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", async function() {
        // Time to reload your interface with accounts[0]!
        accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        // accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        console.log(accounts);
      });
    }
    listenMMAccount();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `chainChanged` event but you have to consider 3 things:

- You have to set listener globally once. Either in navbar, or if using provider in provider or in next.js in _app component
- When chain changed, you should reload the page, recommended by metamask:

> We strongly recommend reloading the page on chain changes, unless you
> have good reason not to.

- after setting a listener for `chainChanged` event, you should remove the listener

here is an example in react/next.js

```
  useEffect(() => {
   async function initWeb3() {
     try {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(
        window.ethereum );
      setListener(window.ethereum);
      // then add logic here
    } catch (error: any) {
      // handle error
    }
  }
   initWeb3();
   return () => removeListener(window.ethereum);
  }, []);

  // this has to be set once globally. metamask suggests
  const setListener = (ethereum) => {
     ethereum.on("chainChanged", pageReload);
  };
  const removeListener = (ethereum) => {
    ethereum.removeListener("chainChanged", pageReload);
  };

  function pageReload() {
    window.location.reload();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Detect change in Metamask account

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
   
      window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", () => {
        window.location.reload();
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when a user account changes on Metamask, you can detect and update it on your interface asynchronously without the need to reload your page as follows, for an example:

```
const checkCurrentAccount = () => {
 if (window.ethereum) {
   window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", async () => {
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
      method: "eth_accounts",
    });
    setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
  });
 }
};

useEffect(() => {
 checkCurrentAccount();
}, []);
```