# Why this error is coming Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, metamask

Here is my code in which error is coming please help me out.

```
initContract: function () {
    $.getJSON('Election.json', function (data) {
      // Get the necessary contract artifact file and instantiate it with truffle-contract
      var ElectionArtifact = data;
      App.contracts.Election = TruffleContract(ElectionArtifact);

      // Set the provider for our contract
      App.contracts.Election.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

      // Listen for events in the contract
      App.listenForEvents();

      web3.currentProvider.publicConfigStore.on('update', function (result) {
        if (result.selectedAddress != App.yourAddress) {
          location.reload();
        }

      });

      return App.showResult();
    });
    return App.bindEvents();
  },
```

error in console is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

Comment: The only place where `on` is used is here `web3.currentProvider.publicConfigStore.on(..` the error means `web3.currentProvider.publicConfigStore` is undefined, or it was never initialized properly.

Comment: @Ismael then what should I do to rectify this error.

Comment: From the MetaMask documentation about [removal of ethereum.publicConfigStore](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#migrating-to-the-new-provider-api) you have to update the code to replace it with a new api, probably `ethereum.on('accountsChanged', handleAccountsChanged);`.

Comment: Perhaps this should help https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42768/how-can-i-detect-change-in-account-in-metamask/49008#49008